# Which should be preferred in this case- simple present or present continuous?

Tags: tense, punctuation

> When Anjali's love is spurned by Major Jaidev, she is dejected. She teams up with Abrush, a terrorist, to wreak havoc on Jaidev unaware that she has put the country's safety in jeopardy.

This is the original form of the sentence. It could be restructured as:

> > When Anjali's love is spurned by Major Jaidev, she is dejected. She teams up with Abrush, a terrorist, to wreak havoc on Jaidev, unaware that she has put the country's safety in jeopardy.

I just added punctuation which I believed was necessary. I wonder why not the sentence goes like **with him/her being unaware** depending on whether the reference is to Anjali or Jaidev which I believe is not proper due to a missing punctuation. Why should present continuous **being unaware** is not used instead of simple present **aware**?

Comment: Without the comma, it's confusing, but that doesn't have anything to do with  tense. The problem is solved simply by placing the clause _"Unaware that she has put the country's safety in jeopardy"_ at the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: "Unaware" is not actually a verb, so tense is not an issue here. But there is no reason why you should not write "being unaware" - though it is quite unnecessary. They mean the same thing.

Comment: I believe **Unaware that she has put the country's safety in jeopardy** in the beginning will not be appositive either. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Being unaware" frequently shows up as a [*participle phrase*](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm), and not the present continuous.  Participle phrases act as adjectives, as in the following sentence:

> *Being unaware of the consequences*, Fred thought it a good idea to kiss the cobra.

The participle phrase "being unaware of the consequences" modifies the noun "Fred".

However, "unaware" by itself is an adjective not a verb.  In your example, *"unaware that she is ..."* is something like an adjective phrase that modifies the noun "Anjali".

> Anjali, *(who is) unaware that she is putting the country in jeopardy*, teams up with a terrorist.
>
> Fred, *(who is) ignorant of reptiles*, tried to kiss a cobra.

(It's possible that this structure is actually called something else, in which case, hopefully, someone will correct me.  These fine distinctions of grammar are above my pay grade.)

The comma, while helpful, is irrelevant to the meaning of the sentence, because it's clear that Anjali is the primary subject, so we can assume any part of the sentence will be about her unless otherwise specified.  (Also, of the three people mentioned, she seems to be the only female.)

Comment: Thanks buddy. In your: **Being unaware of the consequences, Fred thought it a good idea to kiss the cobra.** I believe it should be **thought it as a good idea** but I may be wrong.

Comment: @AnubhavSingh  "thought it a good idea" is short for "thought it **would be** a good idea".  I don't know if this counts as an ellipsis or if it's a legitimate idiomatic structure, .e.g "He thought it better to leave the cobra alone"